# Can Numpy beat keras run time of matrix multiplication on CPU?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, cpu

I want to compare on 'CPU' the runtime between Keras and NumPy for the multiplication operations.

here is my code:

```
######################################################################
# test : predictions & run_time
######################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # to ignore warning errors
    import time
    import tensorflow.keras.backend as keras
    import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
    import numpy as np

    A = np.random.randn(3, 200, 200, 3).astype('float32')

    avg_time = [0, 0]
    outs = [[], []]

    n_simulations = 3
    for _ in range(n_simulations):
        # Keras
        t1 = time.time()
        dense_keras = layers.Dense(units=1024, activation=None, input_shape=(3, 200, 200, 3))
        x = keras.constant(A)
        o1 = dense_keras(x).numpy()
        avg_time[0] += (time.time() - t1) / n_simulations
        outs[0].append(o1)

        # NumPy method
        W, b = dense_keras.get_weights()
        t1 = time.time()
        o2 = np.dot(A, W) + b
        avg_time[1] += (time.time() - t1) / n_simulations
        outs[1].append(o2)

    print("difference of predictions ", [(o1 - o2).sum() for o1, o2 in zip(*outs)])
    print("the average run time of keras: ", avg_time[0], "the average run time  of our implementation: ", avg_time[1])
    print('Ratio speed: (Numpy/keras)', avg_time[1] / avg_time[0])

#################################################
# result
#################################################

# difference of predictions  [-2.4116001e-05, -2.4116001e-05, -2.4116001e-05]
# the average run time of keras:  0.2522510687510172 the average run time  of Numpy:  2.8951672712961836
# Ratio speed: (Numpy/keras) 11.477324102653613
```

I'm not sure if NumPy on CPU is faster than TensorFlow … but in my implementation (a simple (np.dot(x,w)+b)) where I use NumPy the time is longer than Keras one.

Any explication why? and what's make Keras faster on CPU? and is there any way to make the NumPy code faster?

Thank you

Comment: yes, "the average run time of keras:  0.2522510687510172, the average run time  of Numpy:  2.8951672712961836"

Comment: does `.get_weights()` return numpy arrays or some other object time that `numpy.dot` has to convert first?

Comment: Try to use `timeit` instead of a test on a small number of trials. `timeit` will test the code N times, with N depending on the actual duration of the first run and will give you mean and std directly.

Comment: `.get_weights()`  return a <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Your testing method is wrong.

Comment: @Mercury what's wrong about it?

Comment: You're putting methods like layers.Dense and .numpy() into the time consideration. Only evaluate the actual matrix multiplication process.